# CACTI's WeatherMap Plugin Label Sync

Tags: cacti

I have some trouble with using Cacti's WeatherMap plugin. Cacti's WeatherMap plugin has many great functions. I want to draw some sync data in the label, but my cacti aren't operated well. who knows the solution?

- Cacti WeatherMap Code

  NODE node09652

  ```
  LABEL {node:this:inpercent:%.1f}
  INFOURL /cacti/graph.php?rra_id=all&local_graph_id=14
  OVERLIBGRAPH /cacti/graph_image.php?rra_id=0&graph_nolegend=true&  graph_height=100&graph_width=300&local_graph_id=14
  ICON images/Cloud-line.png
  TARGET gauge:C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\cacti\\rra\\2\\26.rrd:cpu:-
  POSITION 340 230
  ```
- Clog Error

  08/28/2017 06:20:52 PM - WEATHERMAP: Poller[0] WARNING: [Map 1] simple.conf: ReadData: NODE node09652, target: gauge:C:\Apache24\htdocs\cacti\rra\2\26.rrd:cpu:- on config line 40 of C:\Apache24\htdocs\cacti\plugins\weathermap\configs\simple.conf had no valid data, according to WeatherMapDataSource_rrd

The Clog Error is "no valid data or not registered .. " And I tried to change the TARGET gauge path, but the error is still occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run for one poller cycle with DEBUG logging turned on in Cacti, and you'll see a lot more log information from Weathermap. If you look for the lines with ReadData in them, you'll see what is happening inside the rrd data plugin - e.g. if the file exists, if the DS names are correct (if not, it will tell you what names are valid), if there is valid data in the RRD file (you'll see the data fetched from rrdtool).

Usually you would see serious warnings even without the debug logging, just before the line you pasted above.